# Basic copy loop problem with range & column iteration

Tags: excel, vba

how can i turn the following into a 500x loop?

```
Range("A14:A6368").Cut Range("B1")
Range("B14:B6368").Cut Range("C1")
Range("C14:C6368").Cut Range("D1")
```

Basically, I copied a table on the web, when I paste into excel, I get it all in 1 column. 
Must be simple, but I've spent hours googling and I cannot find the solution!

Thank you!

Comment: So... slightly confused - your example has multiple columns (A, B, C) but you say "You get it all in 1 column." Is your code right (because it seems like you could just cut `A14:C6368` and paste in B1 to achieve what it is doing)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following perhaps:

```
Dim i As Long 
For i = 1 To 500
    Range(Cells(14, i), Cells(6368, i)).Cut Destination:=Cells(1, i + 1)
Next
```

You can also use `Offset`.

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To 499
    Range("A14:A6368").Offset(, i).Cut Destination:=Range("B1").Offset(, i)
Next
```

Comment: That's amazing, thank you so much! I'm suprised by how long it takes to run, but that's exactly what I needed. You're a star!

Comment: @Pierre73953 well there are ways of simplifying - I'm still confused why you need a loop/VBA here, per my previous [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58523353/basic-copy-loop-problem-with-range-column-iteration/58523444?noredirect=1#comment103372096_58523353)

Comment: The data is in 1 column. Rows 2 and 3 in the code i posted were just me showing the automation needed. Basically, every 14th row, the rest of the column is pasted onto the next column, row 1, and so on ~500x, which is what your function does.